# Easiest way to get logs from beta tester iOS device?

Tags: ios, xcode, console, crash-reports, beta

I have a beta tester who is experiencing a crash upon launching my app. I have Flurry Crashlytics enabled, but I guess it isn't lasting for long enough for those reports to be sent out.

He's a remote user, so I can't plug his computer into my computer, and I doubt he has XCode or any other development tools installed on his own computer.

How could I get the crash log from his phone so I could have a better idea of where the issue lies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have him access the logs directly on the device under Settings, Privacy, Diagnostics & Usage, D&U data. Here it lists the crash logs. You could have him copy and paste the log to send it to you.

Comment: Weirdly, I forced my own crash, and it isn't appearing under Diagnostics & Usage Data. Any ideas why it might not be showing there? I ran from xcode, then stopped the app, and ran it by tapping on it, forcing the crash.

Comment: Did you load a release build?

Comment: Nope. And my user has the log, so it's fine.